# Unknown Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings, strtok, string-literals

I am writing a program that splits a sentence and returns an array of strings of the individual words in the sentence. I have written the two functions below but when I run them I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped) error`. Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: show the code that calls these functions

Comment: @MiguelPrz Just made an edit now.

Comment: @Brandon Look at what you posted and **only** what you posted. Can we reproduce the problem you're experiencing with *only* that code? if not, it's not enough. We need a [mcve] to help you. I strongly suggest, however, that you read Vlad's answer. It's going to be relevant no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You declared an array of pointers to string literals.

```
  char *hamlet[] = {"Give every man thy ear but few thy voice, Neither a borrower nor a lender be,",
                    "For loan oft loses both itself and friend",
                    "And borrowing dulls the edge of husbandry, This above all to thine own self be true"};
```

When within the called function

```
char **words = splitString(hamlet[j], &size);
```

you are trying to change the string literals using the function `strtok`

```
char* word = strtok(theString, " ");
```

You may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You should declare a two-dimensional character array initialized by the string literals.

Pay attention to that the function `splitString` does not set the parameter `arraySize` declared as a referenced type.

So using the variable `size` in calls like this

```
displayWords(words, size);
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

In turn the function `clean` is also incorrect

```
void clean(char *words[], int numWords) {
        int i=0;
        for (i=0; i<numWords; ++i) {
                free(words[i]);
        }
        free(words);

}
```

You have only one dynamically allocated array `words`. So calling the function free for its elements like

```
free(words[i]);
```

again invokes undefined behavior.

The function could be defined simpler

```
void clean( char *words[] ) 
{
        free(words);
}
```

Comment: Do you think it would be better to not use strtok() then? Or instead, do you know how I would declare a two-dimensional character array initialized by the string literals? Would that be in my split function or in the main function. Sorry I am still a beginner in C and apologize if these are dumb questions.

Comment: @Brandon you could declare the array like  char hamlet[][SOME_MAX_LENGTH] = { /* the same list of initializers */ };

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change that part of the code. Do you know how I could implement this function without using strtok() in that case?

Comment: @Brandon In this case you can not split an element of the array into strings. You could use functions strspn and strcspn to find pointers to beginners of words. Or using these functions you could allocate a memory for each word and copy a word from the source string into the allocated memory.

Comment: I am trying to allocate memory for each word and copy a word from the source into the allocated memory, but am still having trouble doing so. How would a function of this sort look?

Comment: @Brandon As I said you should use the functions strspn and strcspn to extract a word. Then you need to allocate a memory for the word and copy it into the allocated memory.

Comment: Do you think I would be able to make a full copy of the original string and then use strtok() without running into a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Brandon  It is not an efficient approach. It is better to extract words using strspn and strcspn and then copy them in allocated memory.

Comment: @Brandon You shall not change your question such a way as you did. Now the  answers will only confuse readers of the question.

Comment: Yes I am fixing it sorry.